# VB .Net Add Dynamic Control on Button Click

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, dynamic-controls

*Hello everyone,*

I'm creating a program, where the user will be able to monitor his budget.
First, the user enters the amount of money used, while afterwards the user should elaborate his expenses.

For example, I've used 20$, elaborated:

- 2$ on Ice cream
- 15$ on Food
- 3$ on Unspecified

The user should be able to click a "+" button, and every time he does that, a field/custom control gets created, where the user can enter a value.

In theory, the user should be able to create infinite amount of fields.
How do I accomplish this? I know how to scan through all the fields user *DirectCast* and etc., I just have no clue on how to create these fields dynamically.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is to use a `DataGridView`. It is a kind of table that allows you to add rows dynamically. You can bind the `DataGridView` to various kinds of data (lists, datasets etc.).

Another way is to use a `TableLayoutPanel` and to add controls dynamically to it. But this this requires more coding in order to keep track of the controls added.

The VB power tools have a data repeater control (it can be used in C# as well). It works basically like a data grid but uses a template for the rows, allowing you to place any controls in any order on the template, that is then repeated for each row.